# Objective C: Detect number of Facebook invites

Tags: objective-c, facebook

I'm trying to detect how many invites the user has sent while logged into their Facebook account. For example, I'm giving the user an option to purchase an item by inviting 3 friends to use the iOS application. If they invite 3, they are rewarded with the item. I'm really stuck on this one. Any help would be great and much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found code snippet for this after much research. I can't remember if it was on here or not, but here it is.

```
- (IBAction)inviteFacebookFriendsButton:(id)sender
{
    // FBSample logic
    // if the session is open, then load the data for our view controller
    if (!FBSession.activeSession.isOpen)
    {
        // if the session is closed, then we open it here, and establish a handler for state changes
        [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:nil
                                           allowLoginUI:NO
                                      completionHandler:^(FBSession *session,
                                                          FBSessionState state,
                                                          NSError *error) {
                                          if (error) {
                                              UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                                                                  message:error.localizedDescription
                                                                                                 delegate:nil
                                                                                        cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                                                        otherButtonTitles:nil];
                                              [alertView show];
                                          } else if (session.isOpen) {


                                          }
                                      }];
    }

    MouseInTheHouseAppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    if (appDelegate.session.isOpen)
    {
        NSMutableDictionary  *postVariablesDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        [postVariablesDictionary setObject:@"Come play Mouse in the House with me!" forKey:@"message"];
        [postVariablesDictionary setObject:@"Invite Friends" forKey:@"title"];

        [FBWebDialogs presentDialogModallyWithSession:[FBSession activeSession] dialog:@"apprequests" parameters:postVariablesDictionary handler:^(FBWebDialogResult result, NSURL *resultURL, NSError *error)
         {
         if (error)
         {
             // Case A: Error launching the dialog or sending request.
             NSLog(@"Error sending request.");
         }
         else
         {
             if (result == FBWebDialogResultDialogNotCompleted)
             {
                 // Case B: User clicked the "x" icon
                 NSLog(@"User canceled request.");
             }
             else
             {
                 NSRegularExpression * regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"to%5B\\d+%5D=(\\d+)"
                                                                                         options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
                                                                                           error:NULL];
                 NSArray * matches = [regex matchesInString:resultURL.absoluteString
                                                    options:0
                                                      range:(NSRange){0, resultURL.absoluteString.length}];
                 NSMutableArray * ids = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:matches.count];
                 for (NSTextCheckingResult * match in matches)
                 {
                     [ids addObject:[resultURL.absoluteString substringWithRange:[match rangeAtIndex:1]]];
                 }

                 NSLog(@"Number of friends invited: %lu", (unsigned long)ids.count);
             }
         }
     }];
    }
}
```